# Polynomial ring, regular local ring and $k$-algebra homomorphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $(A,\mathfrak{m})$ be a regular local ring such that $\dim(A)=d$, $\mathfrak{m}=\langle f_1,\ldots, f_d\rangle$ and $A/\mathfrak{m} = k$.

**Edit:** $A$ contains its residue field.

Next, consider the $k$-algebra homomorphism $\phi: k[x_1,\ldots, x_d] \to A$ defined as $\phi(x_i)=f_i$.

Then **how can I show** that for every $n\geq 1$

$$ A = \phi(k[x_1,\ldots,x_d]) + \mathfrak{m}^n, \quad \text{and} \quad \mathfrak{m}^n = \phi(\langle x_1, \ldots, x_d\rangle^n)+\mathfrak{m}^{n+1}$$

**my attempt**

Since $A$ is local, $A\setminus\mathfrak{m}$ is the set of all units of $A$. Therefore, every element of $1+\mathfrak{m}$ is a unit. Moreover, since it is regular, we have $\dim_k\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2 = d$. I believe that these two facts should imply the above claim, however am unable to see it.

Comment: $A$ is also a $k$-algebra, right?

Comment: @EvansGambit yes. Forgot to include that $A$ contains its residue field.

Answer (score 2):

Since $A$ is a regular local ring, there is an isomorphism (see Atiyah-Mcdonald-Comm Algebra, Theorem 11.22) $$ \psi: k[x_1, \dots, x_d]\to G_\mathfrak{m}(A)=\bigoplus_{n\geq 0}\mathfrak{m}^n/\mathfrak{m}^{n+1}$$ sending $$x_i\mapsto f_i.$$

Consider $$\gamma: G_\mathfrak{m}(A)\xrightarrow{\psi^{-1}}  k[x_1, \dots, x_d]\xrightarrow{\phi} A.$$

Now the formulae you are asking for will follow from the existence of the map $\gamma$ above.

For example:

**(2)** For $a\in \mathfrak{m}^n$, $\gamma(\bar{a})=\phi(\psi^{-1}(\bar{a}))$. So in $A$, Since $\psi^{-1}(\bar{a}-\overline{\phi(\psi^{-1}(\bar{a}))})=0$, here $\bar{.}$ denotes modulo $\mathfrak{m}^{n+1}$.

Now $\psi^{-1}$ is an isomorphism, we get  $a-\phi(\psi^{-1}(\bar{a}))\in \mathfrak{m}^{n+1}.$ Hence $$a=\phi(\psi^{-1}(\bar{a}))+a-\phi(\psi^{-1}(\bar{a}))=\phi(\psi^{-1}(\bar{a})) \mod \mathfrak{m}^{n+1}.$$

Comment: What do you mean by "follow from the existence of the map $\gamma$"? According to Atiyah-MacDonald, the isomorphism you used is equivalent to the fact that $\mathfrak{m} =\langle f_1,\ldots, f_d\rangle$. Is there a direct way of proving the above equalities, instead of using this graded ring?

Comment: Added an argument for the 2nd part. My guess would be that the direct approach would essentially be going through the steps in the proof of the isomorphism $\psi$.